# Service worker: Redirecting a user to different url when he clicks the notification

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

This snippet helps in either bring in the app tab in focus or open a new tab with that URL. If the tab is already open, is there a way to change the URL (based on the notification the user clicked).?

```
  event.waitUntil(
  clients.matchAll({
      type: 'window'
  })
  .then(function(windowClients) {
      for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
          var client = windowClients[i];
          if (url.test(client.url) && 'focus' in client) {
              return client.focus();
          }
      }
      if (clients.openWindow) {
          return clients.openWindow('/#/chat');
      }
  })
  );
```

Comment: I would suggest a different architecture whereby you send a message to clients, which then determine what to do in whatever situation you need. IOW, if it needs to focus, `client.postMessage('focus')`. If it needs to open a new window, `client.postMessage('window', url)`. If it needs to redirect, `client.postMessage('redirect', url)`

Comment: Agreed! This is what I'm doing right now, but I was wondering that since I already have the tag, was it possible to do it from here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`WindowClient.navigate()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#client-navigate-method) method sounds like what you want. You should be able to do something like:

```
// Assume that you want to find the first window that is currently open
// to originalUrl, and navigate that window to navigationUrl.
// If there is no window currently at originalUrl, then open a new window.
event.waitUntil(
  clients.matchAll({type: 'window'})
    .then(clients => clients.filter(client => client.url === originalUrl))
    .then(matchingClients => {
      if (matchingClients[0]) {
        return matchingClients[0].navigate(navigationUrl)
                 .then(client => client.focus());
      }

      return clients.openWindow(navigationUrl);
    })
);
```