# Service Worker onClick event - How to open url in window withing sw scope?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, service-worker

I have service worker which handles push notification click event:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
    e.notification.close();

     e.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(e.notification.data.url)
      );

});
```

When notification comes it takes url from *data* and displays it in new window.

The code works, however, I want different behavior. When User clicks on the link, then it should check if there is any opened window within service worker scope. If yes, then it should focus on the window and navigate to the given url.

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39492934/709897) but it is not exactly what I want.

Any idea how it can be done?

P.S. I wrote this code but it still doesn't work. The first two messages are however shown in the log.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
    e.notification.close();
    var redirectUrl = e.notification.data.redirect_url.toString();
    var scopeUrl = e.notification.data.scope_url.toString();
    console.log(redirectUrl);
    console.log(scopeUrl);

    e.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({type: 'window'}).then(function(clients) {
            for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                  console.log(clients[i].url);
                  if (clients[i].url.toString().indexOf(scopeUrl) !== -1) {
                        // Scope url is the part of main url
                        clients[i].navigate(givenUrl);
                        clients[i].focus();
                        break;
                  }
            }
        })
    );

});
```

Comment: Try to console.log the clients the matchAll returns. Just before the for loop. If the length of the clients is 0 then the for loop is never executed, right

Comment: yes, you are right again. clients are empty so I have added "includeUncontrolled: true" into the matchAll. Now it throws "Service worker event waitUntil() was passed a promise that rejected with 'ReferenceError: givenUrl is not defined'"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is the piece of code which works as expected. Notice that I am passing scope_url together with redirect_url into the web notification. After that I am checking if scope_url is part of sw location. Only after that I navigate to redirect_url.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (e) {
    e.notification.close();
    var redirectUrl = e.notification.data.redirect_url;
    var scopeUrl = e.notification.data.scope_url;

    e.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true, type: 'window'}).then(function(clients) {
            for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
                  if (clients[i].url.indexOf(scopeUrl) !== -1) {
                        // Scope url is the part of main url
                        clients[i].navigate(redirectUrl);
                        clients[i].focus();
                        break;
                  }
            }
        })
    );

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, most of the code you linked to works here.

- First retrieve all the clients
- If there are more than one, choose one of them

  - Navigate that to somewhere and focus
- Else open a new window

Right?

```
event.waitUntil(
  clients.matchAll({type: 'window'})
    .then(clients => {
      // clients is an array with all the clients
      if (clients.length > 0) {
        // if you have multiple clients, decide
        // choose one of the clients here
        const someClient = clients[..someindex..]
        return someClient.navigate(navigationUrl)
          .then(client => client.focus());
      } else {
        // if you don't have any clients
        return clients.openWindow(navigationUrl);
      }
    })
);
```

Comment: yes, you are right. I have wrote similar code but it still doesn't work. I will edit the question