# Is there a possibility for sending a Firebase Background Message to a SubUrl via webpush?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using Firebase Messaging to send simple Messages to a simple MVC APP.

I am using postman(for testing purpose) to send the Message via the google api:

- POST
- https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/shk-notifications-dev/messages:send
- oAuth 2.0 with Bearer Access Token

The message can be received via javascript in my MVC App. Both *messaging.onMessage()* and *messaging.onBackgroundMessage()* are functional.

I would like to add an URL to my message, so that a click on a background Message will change the focus/open the site to a subUrl.
Therefore I added the webpush-->fcm_options-->Link to my Json Body

```
{
    "message":{
        "token":
            "f0OUYjScb6kr6yVmt3inOY:APA91bFK4og6VpvtgPOjATtzW3hcAs....",
        "notification": {
            "title": "Postman Title",
            "body": "Postman message body"
        },
         "webpush": {
             "fcm_options": {
         "link": "https://localhost:44373/home/about"
         }
        }
    }
```

}

If a send my message, the background message is received
[BackgroundMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68aVp.png)

and a click on the message changes the focus to the site **https://localhost:44373** but **NOT** to the subUrl **https://localhost:44373/home/about**

What am I missing? How to configure the Background Message Webpush-Url to open my subUrl

**Extension to the Question**

Code für MVC Application. MVC Razor Site with javascript file "firebase-messaging-sw.js"

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.4.1/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyDUnZvyzosgjJWeE0e_x_OXBaJbwfF9FlU',
        authDomain: 'shk-test-5107d.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://shk-test-5107d-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app',
        projectId: 'shk-test-5107d',
        storageBucket: 'shk-test-5107d.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: '667724451196',
        appId: '1:667724451196:web:824d1bda6f43a1ec6c28f9',
        measurementId: 'G-FD30HYTH6M'
    };
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(
    (payload) => {
        console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
        //console.log('before' + self.location.href);
        self.location = 'https://localhost:44373/Home/About';
        console.log('after' + self.location.href);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the link which has the same host with the registered service worker can be opened. you will have to redirect the user with something like the following:

```
    "webpush": {
        "fcm_options": {
            "link": "example.com" + "?url=" + "https://example.com/home/about"
        }
    }
```

This will require additional setup within your app to route the URL properly

If you open the URL in the service worker directly, you need to make a request with the device to open the URL in question:

```
  // Do something with your WindowClient
});
```

just be aware that if the device doesn't allow permission to open the URL, it will throw an `InvalidAccessError` error.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/openWindow

Comment: Ah ok, so there is no possibility to redirect the User via the click on the Background Notification Message? That means i have to implement the url redirect in the messaging.onBackgroundMessage() function in the "firebase-messaging-sw.js" file

Comment: Correct, You can also look at dynamic links as well

Comment: Dynamic links could be a possible solution. I will look into this. 

I tried something like this: (window.location.href cannot be used, because at the 
time the Function is called the window Object wasn't loaded yet because the focus change did not happened yet)

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(
    (payload) => {
        console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
        self.location.href = '/Home/About';
    });

The redirect is not happening with the approach

Comment: this is because the location object hasn't been populated yet, you could wait for it, or simply pass the URL as the location instead of the href

Comment: Location instead of href is not working for me. for example: self.location = 'https://localhost:44373/Home/About';

Comment: And i have no idea how to wait for the popution of the location. Can you show me a code snippet? I cannot wait with then() for the onBackgroundMessage() function

Comment: I'm not familiar with `self.location` - but you should be able to hook into the browser directly with `window.location` or `window.location.assign(url);`

Comment: Already tried that, same issue, window is not recognized because not loaded yet. So there has to be a way to wait for the execution of the function and the resulting focus change.

Comment: what framework are you using? and where is the function called within your app? it might be a simple order of operations

Comment: I edited the question to include the javascript file

Comment: Thanks for the Code snippet. this means you are redirecting before opening the app. to do this, Window does not exist until the page is open. as such you define a new request with `self.clients.openWith(url)`

Comment: I also found some similar question, you can use their code example per your needs
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46549495/2301161